# Предлагать или предложу?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Дело вот в чем,мы были с Друзями и я предложил одному выпить и он отказался и я сказал «второй раз не предложу» на что другой гость сказал что так не правильно а правильно будет «второй раз предлагать не буду « сидим и спорим кто прав
Помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Как всегда, с интересом прочитала первый ответ, но все-таки придется обратиться к «грамматической» прозе.

Итак, мы сравниваем два варианта: *Второй раз **предлагать не буду.** — *Второй раз **не предложу**.**

С точки зрения грамматики это разный вид глаголов  ***предложу/ предлагать*** (совершенный и несовершенный), и оба варианта возможны. Выбор надо делать **по ситуации.**

Предлагать выпить можно несколько раз, как бы уговаривать. Так обычно и делается, поэтому подтекст такой: ***уговаривать не буду.***  Фраза  в таком виде выглядит устойчивой, поэтому она привычна на слух.

А вот фраза «не предложу второй раз» такого **подтекста не имеет,** поэтому не воспринимается как корректная, хотя грамматически она тоже  возможна.

Поэтому лучше сказать все-таки так: ***Второй раз предлагать не буду.***

Comment: Я не соглашусь, уговаривать - это как раз делать предложение. А предлагать - глагол действия, - давать/класть. Буду, как я и писал, это не предикат, а вспомогательный глагол времени.

Comment: Ну самое знаменитое: Вражду положу между тобою и между женою - нет смысла класть. "ежели кораблей купецких не случится, то положу на капер" - каперы, это какие-то частники, если купцы не согласятся, договорюсь с каперами. Где она, тут положу свои косточки - сложить головы тоже, переносные значения.  Нет, брат! не расставайся с отцовским благословением: я положу и за тебя и за себя. Ну и тд. Теперь положу перо за ухо и пойду опять на палубу - положу перо за ухо - фразеологизм, перестану писать. "-ложить" - относится к фразеологизмам либо словесному взаимодействию, а не к физическим действиям.

Comment: Не предложу - практически не встречается в литературе, потому что кривая форма, от не предлагать. Отрицание может быть только у глагола действия. Не делать что-то.

Comment: Возможно, если добавить усиления отрицания, то может быть: не предложу ничего более. Но именно так, а не "больше не предложу".

Comment: Соглашусь с вашим несогласием...))  Но я же говорю, грамматическая проза, грамматика языка, коммуникативность речи, куда от них...  (Но вас я все равно слушаю с интересом и думаю, как бы получше понять и сформулировать  вашу идею))  Уговаривать не буду – это не буду больше (еще, второй и третий раз) предлагать. ПРИМЕРЫ предложений с "не предложу":  https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkUqGAoICAEQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQvdC1INC/0YDQtdC00LvQvtC20YMwAQ==  ПЕРЕВОД https://context.reverso.net/перевод/русский-английский/не+предложу

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что такое коммуникативность речи). И зачем примеры переводов? В английском тоже неразбериха с этим, но они используют разные корни lie -ложь и лечь/лежать, logue - относящееся к логике, собиранию вместе, отсюда и лига, религия, и еще log, как они объясняют от дров сложенных логом, или лог - это бревно. Ну у них все сложно, потому что нет деления сферы духовной и внешнего мира вещей, поэтому у них все скатывается в формализм или в абстракцию. Примеры да, я на них и намекаю, там весьма скупо, по сравнению с "не предлагаю" и "не предлагать" которых больше сотни.

Comment: У меня просто появилась идея, что духовные понятия в принципе под отрицание не очень подходят. То есть сказать не мечтаю, не думаю, не буду думать - это криво. Можно сказать "больше думать не буду", но не "больше не думаю" - без какого-то дополнения, о чем не думаю. То есть это скорее связки, а не глаголы действия, где не будет относится к дополнению. Больше не думаю о том - теперь думаю не о том. А если человек не думает - то как он отвечает тогда на вопрос? короче логические заковыки. Не "не мечтаю", а нет мечты.

Comment: Ну или как я писал в посте про мечты, верить в - это верифицировать вещь. Правильная форма была бы верить Богу или верить Бога, но не верить в бога - форма которая появляется только когда появляется идея не верить ни во что - нигилизм, в середине 19 века. Тогда бог становится вещью, начинает существовать в мире вещей, точнее отсутствовать. Вот примеры: https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=ClEqIQoICA8QChgyIAoQBSAAKKKoqficifYCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCJQojCiEKA3JlcRIaChjQstC10YDQuNGC0Ywg0LIg0LHQvtCz0LAwAQ==

Толстой, кстати, один из сомневающихся, что показательно.

Comment: Спасибо!! Еще немного – и я уже начну вас понимать!  Еще одно лето, или вечер, или дождик, или тень...

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что есть два так называемых корня с чередованием в русском язык лог/лаг/лег и леж, и лож(получилось больше чем, два). Номинально это вроде как один корень, но на деле у этих корней разные смысловые значения.

Предложить/предложу - предполагать, высказать точку зрение, от логос, логика и даже ложь.

А предлагать - это давать, скорее всего от класть, родственное лечь - [легос](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*legh-?ref=etymonline_crossreference). И мне еще кажется оно родственное слову лог+ин, которое [лежащее полено - log/clogge](https://www.etymonline.com/word/clog?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_13833)

Кстати, в английском тоже такая путаница есть, что [ложь и лечь](https://www.etymonline.com/word/lie#etymonline_v_9487) это одно и тоже, но там нет букв Г(Ч) и Ж.

То есть предлагать - это делать что-то доступным, то что лежит, бери то, что лежит.

А предложение - это фраза, какое-то высказывание. Предложение невесте - это заключение словесного договора о помолвке, предложение руки и сердца, причем в образном выражении. Предлагаю руку и сердце - не уместно, так как "кладу руку и сердце" буквально.

> Бабакина (злобно и удивленно). Что?
> Боркин. Предлагаю руку и сердце. Я люблю вас страстно, бешено.

Комедия Чехова, ну тут это шутка.

Или вот Островский, но тут игра слов:

> [Евдоким Егорыч Стыров (муж, 50, 1831, очень богатый человек)]Я тебе и не предложу миллионов, Евлалия; я предложу другое, что, может быть, тебе покажется дороже.
> [Евлалия Андревна (жен, 30, 1851, жена Стырова)]Что же?
> Стыров. Полную свободу.
> Стырова(удивленная) Свободу?.

Предложу миллионы - пообещаю миллионы.

Также у него же:

> Я мог предложить вам только нищету, и вы бы ее приняли.

Пообещать. Обеспечить. Не совсем дать, несовершенная форма, предположение.

С другой стороны:

> У него вообще явилась теперь удивительная способность вовремя отрешаться, от людей, относиться к ним в меру, не предлагать им, чего они не желают и в чем не имеют нужды, не навязываться.

Тут четко читается "не давать им".

> Не предлагать же мне гг. покупателям полюбоваться на изобилие красующихся в моем магазине французских книг, когда им нужно совершенно другое.

Не предлагать - советовать сделать. Предлагать употребляется в сфере услуг, или когда дело касается конкретных вещей.

Хотя в современном языке часто можно услышать в рекламе: у меня деловое предложение - ну очевидно от корня лож, а не лог, ничего не дадут, а просто обманут). Замануха.

Также нет слова ложить, а есть слово класть. Положить, отложить - класть что-то на потом. А отлагать - это откладывать в сторону.

Прилагать - класть вплотную, прилагать или прикладывать усилия. А приложить - это уровнять, сровнять, приложится к иконе/мощам - прикоснуться губами, прикладываться, в духовном смысле. Ума не приложу, прилагай ум не говорят.

Заложить - это понятие, сделать основу, или еще заложить имущество. Заложить церковь, заложить город - понятия всякие.

А залагать - закладывать, закласть, затыкать (дыру).

Наложить кучу - бранное. Потому что неверное употребление.

Залог - конкретный термин, конкретная сумма. Дать в залог. Дать/взять в долг.

Но одолжить - взять деньги на что-то еще. Вернуть долг, но не должное, должное обещанное, долг - обязанность.

Но заложенное имущество - понятие имущество, общее. Имущество еще нужно оценить.

Заложник - идеологический пленник, сам он не нужен, но используется для получения того, что требуют, помимо него самого.

Сложить - выполнить операцию сложения, сложить фигуру.

Слагать - складывать, например стихи, сочинять, объединять.

Ложь - понятие общее.

Лгать - глагол, говорить ложь.

Так что вывод:

Вам посоветовали верно. Предлать выпить вино/водку. Предложение - это дело, идея. Предложение собраться выпить, потому что собраться, но предлагать выпить - давать выпить.